# Tools or Methods for generating Platform Icons and Splash images in Apache Cordova config

Tags: cordova, icons, splash-screen

I was getting ready to update my icon from the default in my first Apache Cordova project when I first noticed there are 32 entries for different variations of the icon in config.xml broken up by platform.

Are there any existing tools or perhaps built in functionality which will take a base image and generate the various platform and device files?

Is the only other options to manually creating each image?

Same question for the splash image.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the ionic CLI.
Please visit their website for more information's on how to install it (it is free).
It is a very fast solution, once you have created a temp project with ionic you will need to copy a splash.png (2732x2732 px resolution) and a icon.png (1024x1024 px resolution) into the temp projects "resources" folder and execute the following command in you console: "ionic cordova resources ios" or "ionic cordova resources android" and you'll have all the files generated inside each platforms directory under "resources" folder.
You can reuse this temp project in the future to generate splash/icon images to all other apps you will have.

Once you have the images, make sure to copy and paste the ionic config.xml entries with the image names into your own config.xml and copy over your generated images into your original res/screens/ios or res/screens/android folders.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this website: https://pgicons.abiro.com/
It works fine, except that I needed to add www/ to path of files in the config.xml snippet provided.

Example:

```
<icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>
```

to be changed as

```
<icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/ldpi.png" />
```